# What does echelon mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

When you solve a system of linear equations, you write down the augmented matrix and reduce this to reduced row **echelon** form. What is the meaning of the word echelon?

Comment: I assume it comes from the military term for a structured arrangement of troops into parallel lines.

Comment: @Bye_World: Please write this as an answer (with maybe a link to something) so that I can upvote and accept.

Comment: I'm not going to write up an answer because this is just a guess.  You can research the etymology of the word yourself if you're really interested.... But [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echelon_formation#/media/File:Echelon_1_(PSF).png) a cool picture from the Wikipedia page on Echelon formation that's pretty suggestive.

Comment: I thought it was a cycling term to describe how the peleton spreads out.  This is akin to having the reduced matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=echelon):

> echelon (n.)
>
> 1796, *echellon*, "step-like arrangement of troops," from French *échelon* "level, echelon," literally "rung of a ladder," from Old French *eschelon*, from *eschiele* "ladder," from Late Latin *scala* "stair, slope," from Latin *scalae* (plural) "ladder, steps," from PIE $\ast$*skand*- "to spring, leap" (see scan (v.)). Sense of "level, subdivision" is from World War I.

Steven Schwartzman's *The Words of Mathematics: An Etymological Dictionary of Mathematical Terms* (MAA, 1994) also attributes the root of the term to the French word *échelon* and its meaning of "rung of a ladder" ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=iuoZSkSOBQsC&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=%22echelon+form%22+etymology+mathematical+terms&source=bl&ots=MTKLaY4sRs&sig=PsWJKy5wL9I0Nz3qy7M3dNGB3Mo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ84DhlcrKAhVjJqYKHc1xD3kQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22echelon%20form%22%20etymology%20mathematical%20terms&f=false) from Google Books).

The earliest appearance of "echelon form" as a linear algebra term that I can find is in Birkhoff and Mac Lane (1953), *A Survey of Modern Algebra* ([link](https://books.google.com/books?id=0DxzPUnaDXMC&dq=%22echelon+form%22+matrix&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22echelon+form%22) from Google Books). Yet, Nathan Jacobson's *Lectures in Abstract Algebra: II. Linear Algebra* (1953) does **not** contain this term. I guess the term was introduced to linear algebra more or less around the 1950s.

Comment: A real success story.  Birkhoff and MacLane introduce the terminology, and now all textbooks use it.  With the use of computers, how long will it be until everyone forgets it?

Answer (score 6):

As has already been suggested, it has its origins in military vocabulary.

The [Wiki article on echelon formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echelon_formation) contains many pictures of stuff in echelon formation, and you can immediately see why one might say that the rows of a row-echelon matrix are in "echelon formation." I would have liked to include the wiki images, but for some reason they would not load. I found another one instead: [image]

Comment: This is a nice explanation but I doubt the  *origin* of the terminology is the military term. Instead, I'd assume both the military and the mathematical usage derive from the fact that echelon means (or at least meant, not sure) something like steps (of a ladder).

Comment: Dear @quid : hrm, it seems by far to be the most likely origin of the mathematical usage to me. Yes, to be pedantic, echelon derives from "rung," but "echelon form" evokes the military usage far more.  Regards

Comment: It could be interesting to investigate this historically. My reasoning is based mainly on how it is called in other languages. If you change on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form to other languages several seem to employ terms that are seem compatible much more with steps or staircase idea than with a military formation.

Comment: In Swedish it is "trappstegsmatris" and searching for "trappsteg" I get images of steps (more staircases than ladders though). German it says "stufenform" or "treppenform" in line with steps and staircases. For the Polish "schodkowa" one finds the staircase-like pyramids when searching. The word is also used in what is called "step function" in English.

Comment: @quid interesting, but I don't buy the connection between rung and stair step. They have decidedly different shapes, and staircases are more like an echelon formation than a ladder. They could have all derived from "echelon formation" and "stair step" directly because of their shapes.

Comment: It is possible this is independent, but I doubt it. There are different types of ladders, too, some quite stair-like. Anyway, if one really wanted to know better one would likely have to search  old literature on how the terms evolved.

Answer (score 3):

It simply means the rows are *ordered* in a unique [hierarchy](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/echelon) by the positions of their leading ones (rows of all zeros being lumped at the bottom).

Comment: @Arthur: Is $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 &0 \\ 0&0& 1\end{pmatrix}$ in row echelon form?

Comment: @Arthur:  Apparently you are thinking of the positions of leading ones but even these are not necessarily diagonal.  The word *echelon* here is applied to the rows and has the sense of level or rank within the matrix.

Comment: @Roland Yes, it is.